# Is normal-QQ plot used for checking linearity assumption in linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, qq-plot

I was wondering if   this way of checking linearity assumption in linear regression is correct or common.
In "Build the Linear Model", one of [the slides](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/doomlab/statsofdoom-files/master/lang_model/Lectures%202019/07.regression/regression.html) (to open it in presentation mode, first download it and then open it in a browser), they created a linear model in R, by

```
model = lm (...)
```

In slide "Linearity" , they seemed to check the linearity assumption of the linear regression model, if I am not mistaken, by

```
plot (model, which = 2)
```

The plot figure is

[image]

The title of the plot is "normal Q-Q". Isn't normal Q-Q plot used for checking normality assumption, and how can it be used for checking linearity assumption?

By the way, what does the argument `which = 2` in `plot()` mean?

Thanks.

Comment: The linearity assumption I take informally to mean that $Xb$ is a good representation of the mean response as a function of $X$.  Non-normal residuals may in practice go along with a poor representation more often than not, but it easy to imagine and to find exceptions, e.g. if residuals are symmetric but have different kurtosis from Gaussian then that will show up on this plot but it is not an indictment of linearity. A plot of residual vs fitted is a better choice, but nothing is essential ... or sufficient.

Comment: Is the plot really a normall QQ plot which is used only for checking if a sample distribution is a normal distribution?

Comment: I am not clear what you are driving at with that comment -- unless the answer is simply yes, that's its main purpose. That doesn't stop it being it useful for other reasons. See #6 at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1551507-have-question-about-winsor2-procedures for example. A normal quantile plot is a good general purpose plot for looking at distributions, althiough like any other kind of plot you have to learn what it shows and how to think about it.

Comment: I am not driving at anything else. My question has always been: is normal QQ plot used for checking linearity assumption in linear regression? Or if you insist it can help more or less, is it a regular or major way to check linearity?

Comment: It's not really about checking linearity at all is my best short summary -- and I am still surprised at any other idea.  I think it's a good principle here that questions should be self-contained and not depend on people reading something else -- although supporting references are always welcome. But I clicked on the link in your question and can just see HTML source code, so I gave up on that.

Comment: I have done my best to describe the slides here. If you really want to read them, download them  as a html file, and open them in your browser.

Comment: Sorry, no inclination to do real work at this! I am not clear what you want or expect from this thread.

Comment: I don't want anything else. I am just surprised that the slides use normal QQ plot to check linearity assumption. I am wondering if I am wrong or the slides are

Comment: We agree on that surprise. As said, I am not going to read the slides to say more.

Comment: I was wondering how you would  recommend to check linearity assumption in linear regression? "A plot of residual vs fitted is a better choice, but nothing is essential ... or sufficient. " Do you mean a plot of residual vs fitted is a better choice for checking linearity assumption? Isn't such a plot used for checking the homoscedasticity assumption (used in one of the slides).

Comment: I think that is at best a new question and more likely something already asked many times over on CV -- and very well answered in just about any decent regression or econometrics text.

Comment: Thank you in advance if you can point me to some of the posts and books.

Comment: It is good practice to do a normal QQ plot of residuals to see if they are normal. Having a normal 'error term' is an assumption of many regression models, and looking at a normal QQ plot of residuals is a sensible way to judge whether that assumption is met. // I am not sure how you got the idea that the main purpose of this plot is to check linearity, and I am not inclined to 'read the slides' to try to find out. It is your job to ask a self-contained question.

Comment: This approach, although wrong, has historical roots going back to Quetelet's *Homme moyen.*  The idea (200 years ago) was that when residuals exhibit Normality, that shows one has captured all the non-random components of variation.  Conversely, then, lack of normality implies a better model is needed (or no statistical model is possible).  At best that's a non-discerning technique: there are far better ways to check for linearity.  BTW, type `?plot.lm` to learn about the values of the `which` parameter.

Comment: As @BruceET is agreeing with my stance on questions being self-contained, I have to suggest that it is inaccurate as well as seemingly impolite to dismiss his comment as if merely a personal view.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. What are some better ways for checking linearity? I am also looking for some good books on using R to perform regressions.

Comment: Standard approaches include diagnostic plots like added-variable plots and predicted vs. actual plots, along with goodness-of-fit tests, especially those based on adding nonlinear functions of the explanatory variables to the model.

Answer (score 0):

QQ plot can also be used to determine whether or not two distribution are **similar** or not. If they are quite similar you can expect the QQ plot to be more linear.

Now coming back to your question how we can check the linearity assumption of linear regression. As you are plotting the graph between the theoretical quantiles  and observed residuals, if your linear model is good enough then the distribution of these two (theoretical quantiles  and observed residuals) statistic variable will be very much similar, so by using QQ plot you can determine this similarity between the distribution and thus verifying your linear model.

`which = 2` in `plot()` means that you are plotting the QQ plot. Some other arguments available are

```
1. plot of residuals against fitted values
2. normal Q-Q plot
3. Scale-Location plot of sqrt(| residuals |) against fitted values  

 ... and more
```

Comment: I think this confuses or conflates finding a linear configuration on a normal quantile plot — which indeed indicates a good approximation to normality — with testing whether the model’s linear structure matches the relationship between outcome and predictors.